# Can 'mutating' be inferred for functions inside structs?

Tags: swift

Why should we be required to specify `mutating` for a function in a struct explicitly? Can't it be inferred automatically from the function body while compiling? If it can't, can you please give me an example where it can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some special examples when the compiler cannot infer mutability because it's the programmer decision to say whether the behavior should be considered as mutable.

For example, when the struct is backed up by a class:

```
struct MyArray<T : AnyObject> {
   let buffer: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

   func append(item: T) {
       buffer.addObject(item)
   }
}

let myArray = MyArray<NSString>()
myArray.append("something")
```

Note that the `append` function is modifying the struct but it doesn't have the `mutating` attribute, so you can use it even on constant variables. If you want to prevent that, you need to add the `mutating` attribute.

I didn't choose the array example accidentally. The dictionaries and arrays in Swift are backed up by classes and they had to choose which methods would be mutating and which wouldn't.

Comment: so, what you mean is its the programmers decision whether adding an element to the ```buffer``` is considered mutating the struct or not ?? Or to put in another way, it is not exactly clear if a constant instance of the struct means the ```buffer``` itself will not change or the elements of the buffer also will not change ??

Comment: @Roshan This is a matter of what behaviour you expect. Take Swift constant arrays (in Beta 2) as an example. They allow you to modify elements but they won't allow you append a new element. It's just a programmer decision.